# Evaluate a parametric function dependent on a random number of parameters

Tags: random, parametric-functions

This is a question related to the evaluation of a parametric function dependent on a random number of parameters.

Consider a "blackBox" that returns a parametric function dependent on time (t) and, randomly, on N parameters: $\{p_1, ..., p_N\}$. At the outset, we don't know what N is. The only way to measure N is to call the blackBox. If the blackBox is called again, N might change.

How to evaluate the box at $t = 1$, $p_1=1$, $p_2=2$ , ...., $p_N=N$?

For concreteness, consider the following "little-black-box":

```
littleblackBox := Module[{parameters},
 parameters = If[RandomReal[] < 0.5, {p1}, {p1, p2}];
 Return[ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] + f[t] == 0, 
    f[0] == Total[parameters]}, f, {t, 0, 1}, parameters]]
 ]
```

It returns a parametric function dependent on time and, randomly, dependent on either one parameter: $\{p_1\}$, or two: $\{p_1, p_2\}$.

Clearly,

```
Evaluate[littleblackBox[##] &[1][t]] /. t -> 1
```

or

```
Evaluate[littleblackBox[##] &[1, 2][t]] /. t -> 1
```

could fail. On the other hand, one might think that

```
evaluatelittleBlackBox := Module[{Np, localBox},
  localBox = littleblackBox;
  Np = Length[localBox[[-2]][[1]]];(*get number of parameters*)
  If[ Np == 1, Evaluate[localBox[##] &[1][t]] /. t -> 1 , 
   Evaluate[localBox[##] &[1, 2][t]] /. t -> 1]
  ]
```

does the work; however, I was able to define this function using as prior knowledge that the little-black-box depends on two parameters at most. This doesn't constitute a satisfactory answer.

Aim: rewrite "evaluatelittleBlackBox" without looking inside the little-black-box!

Comment: Do you know that the "black box" is always a `ParametricFunction[...]` object? Or could it be any type of function-like expression?

Comment: It is always a ParametricFunction[...] object.

Comment: And how should the parameter values be chosen? Randomly? From a long enough list? From `1` to `n`?

Comment: In principle from 1 to N. But I wrote the problem in this way for the sake of being concrete. Choosing them randomly or from a long enough list works for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ParametricFunction`, you can get the parameters using the following code:

```
littleblackBox@"Parameters"
(* {p1, p2} *)
```

It is then straightforward to construct a list of appropriate length and to pass it to the function using [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
func = littleblackBox
(* ParametricFunction[ <> ] *)

nParams = Length@func@"Parameters"
(* 1 *)

args = Range@nParams
(* {1} *)

func @@ args
(* InterpolatingFunction[ <> ] *)

(func @@ args)[1]
(* 0.367879 *)
```